# Rotate Rect along line

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

First project in qt.

I'm having trouble translating/rotating a rect along a line. Basically i would want to align the rect with the position of the line. When i change position of the circle the rect should translate along the line. See images below.

[image]

[image]

What i have at the moment

```
w_len = len(str(weight)) / 3 * r + r / 3
weight_v = Vector(r if w_len <= r else w_len, r)
weight_rectangle = QRectF(*(mid - weight_v), *(2 * weight_v))
painter.drawRect(weight_rectangle)
```

*mid is just a vector with coordinates at half of the link , weight_v is a vector based on the text size.

Any pointers , should i look at adding a translate to the painter ? Whenever i try to add translation to the painter it breaks the other shapes as well.

```
t = QTransform()
t.translate(-5 ,-5)
t.rotate(90)
painter.setTransform(t)
painter.drawRect(weight_rectangle)
painter.resetTransform()
```

Update:

With below answer i was able to fix the rotation. Many thanks, looks like my text is not displaying correctly.

[image]

I have the following code:

```
painter.translate(center_of_rec_x, center_of_rec_y);
painter.rotate(- link_paint.angle());
rx = -(weight_v[0] * 0.5)
ry = -(weight_v[1] )
new_rec = QRect(rx , ry, weight_v[0], 2 * weight_v[1])
painter.drawRect(QRect(rx , ry, weight_v[0] , 2 * weight_v[1] ))
painter.drawText(new_rec, Qt.AlignCenter, str(weight))
```

Update2:

All is fine , was a mistake in my code. I was taking the wrong link angle.

Thx.

Comment: provide  a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotation is always done according to the origin point (0, 0), so you need to translate to the origin point of the rotation and then apply it.

Also, when applying any temporary change to the painter, `save()` and `restore()` should be used: in this way the current state of the painter is stored, and that state will be restored afterwards (including any transformation applied in the meantime). Painter states can be nested, and one could save multiple times to apply multiple "layers" of painter state modifications. Just remember that the **all** states must be restored to the base status before releasing (ending) the painter.

Since you didn't provide an MRE, I created a small widget to show how this works:

[image: rectangle rotation example]

```
class AngledRect(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(200, 200)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)

        contents = self.contentsRect()
        # draw a line from the top left to the bottom right of the widget
        line = QtCore.QLineF(contents.topLeft(), contents.bottomRight())
        qp.drawLine(line)

        # save the current state of the painter
        qp.save()
        # translate to the center of the painting rectangle
        qp.translate(contents.center())
        # apply an inverted rotation, since the line angle is counterclockwise
        qp.rotate(-line.angle())

        # create a rectangle that is centered at the origin point
        rect = QtCore.QRect(-40, -10, 80, 20)
        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.white)
        qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
        qp.drawRect(rect)
        qp.drawText(rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, '{:.05f}'.format(line.angle()))
        qp.restore()

        # ... other painting...
```

For simple transformations, using `translate` and `rotate` is usually enough, but the above is almost identical to:

```
        transform = QtGui.QTransform()
        transform.translate(contents.center().x(), contents.center().y())
        transform.rotate(-line.angle())
        qp.save()
        qp.setTransform(transform)
        # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The MRE is missing as i'm working on someone else code and modifying to learn the basics , basically just learning... ; thanks for the info.

Comment: quick question , in your example , how you deal with the text. I manage with your help to solve the rotation( was hard to wrap my head around reseting the x,y). Let me update the question with what i'm seeing on the text